# Can I get ticketed this way?

Tags: police, new-york-state

I was driving my new car at about 85mph in a rural area in New York, when a car I passed sped up behind me blinked his lights.  I slowed down and the driver appeared to be video taping me with his phone. He followed me until he exited, blinked his lights again at me before he exited.  Can I be ticketed for this event?   It seems that in order for him to speed check me, he would need to speed as well.   Thoughts please?

Answer (score 3):

If he was a private actor, his conduct generally isn't relevant. While there's a "no clean hands" concept in civil law, it generally doesn't apply to criminal law, and evidence gathered by private actors while they were breaking the law is generally admissible.

However, the other driver would have to authenticate the evidence, which means testifying under oath that they were speeding. And they would have to establish that they were speed checking you correctly. They would have to establish that their speedometer was working correctly, that they had matched your speed, that they recorded their speed correctly, etc., and a court likely wouldn't accept them as competent to give testimony on a speed check.

Also, states generally don't allow prosecuting violations unless a police officer witnessed them, so unless you were speeding to the point of a misdemeanor, you're almost certainly safe.

Comment: Speeding is never a misdemeanor in New York.

Comment: @phoog So going 120 mph in a 25 mph zone is just a violation?

Comment: Isn't "video taping" you with their phone while driving a crime too?

Comment: @WeatherVane Depends on the state. It could be considered distracted driving. But technically, it would be a violation, not a crime.

Comment: It's [prohibited](https://www.josephperrini.com/what-are-new-yorks-laws-on-cell-phones-and-driving/) in the OP's locale.